# debugging error in visual studio 2010

Tags: devexpress

Ι'm using microsoft visual studio 2010 with Devexpress (Evaluation Product) , 
when every time doing debug , this error always appear

> Unable to resolve type 'DevExpress.Patch.InMemoryPatch,
>   DevExpress.Patch.Common, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7fc7bfca2443de66' (file = licenses.licx)

Comment: The error says that you using some kind of tool/patch on your side which breaks the licensing mechanism of DevExpress products. Thus, just stop to violate of US and international copyright laws...

Answer (score 3):

The error says that you using some kind of tool/patch on your side which breaks the licensing mechanism of **Dev*** products. That violates US and international copyright laws.. Well unless your use is justified e.g. research then reapply that patch or get a new one.

Removing that line of code in license file will also fix the issue, probably someone who initially started that project might have used some king of **patch**.